# Dealing with repeated measures in classification and logit model

Tags: classification, repeated-measures, logit

I have a dataset of STDs test results (4 responses), 25 categorical attributes, and around 12,000 entries. I want to build a classification model for each test (0: if the patient has not been contaminated, and 1: if they have). 
The entries of the dataset are people coming for testing, and some of them have visited the testing center more than once. Does it make sense to keep all the entries for them or should I keep just one? If I am to keep only one, is the last entry the best choice for that?
If I want to create 4 logit models to predict the test outcome for each test, would it make sense to keep all entries even though that violates the independence assumption?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot ignore the lack of independence, so you have two options:

1. Keep only one entry per person, but it would be the first one, since that is what you have for people who have only one entry.
2. Keep all entries, but use a statistical adjustment for the variance estimates to account for the potential within-person correlation. This is called a marginal model, and a common approach for fitting it is GEE (generalized estimating equations).